# Report based on columns' unique values

Tags: excel

I have a list of id numbers, in column A. In columns B, C, D, E, etc, I have values that belong to each id.

I have not found a way to make the opposite:

For each value found in columns B, C, D, E, how could I revert the report, in order to get the following output:

Input:

```
id B     C      D       E
1  value1 value2 value3  value4
```

output report:

```
value1 found in the following ids 1, 14, 15, 17,...

value2 found in the following ids 1, 4, 5, 7,...

....
```

I cannot make it with vlookup, or index match, how would you suggest I treated this?

Comment: You could do a similar thing to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?